# I want to set `nodeadkeys`, but where?

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout, dead-keys

I want to configure my keyboard to write characters like `^` or `~` with just one click. A friend told me, I have to set `nodeadkeys` somewhere, but not the place. So, where to change this configuration (preferably manually in a `.conf` file).

What I already tried:

The only seemingly meaningful documentation I found about setting `nodeadkeys`, was in [this German website](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Sonderzeichen). This page describes different ways to get through the GUI menus, but all of them don't work on my freshly setup Ubuntu system (with gnome). Maybe it was written for older versions. It also describes how to set it manually in the `xorg.conf`, which should be found in `/etc/X11/`, which is also not the case. I looked for an xorg.conf all over the system (`sudo find / -name "xorg.conf"`) but also didn't find anything. No result yet.

Comment: Are you on Ubuntu 12.04 or another version?

Comment: Yes, and the answer below is working for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every keyboard layout that uses dead keys by default has a corresponding (eliminate dead keys)-version. To change keyboard layout, go to **System Settings > Keyboard Layout** and press the **+**-button to add a new layout.

If, for example, you want a German layout without dead keys, search for "german" in the search field. You should find the option "German (eliminate dead keys)".
[image]

Comment: Yeah there is a setting in the Keyboard settings dialog for Kubuntu too.

Comment: I didn't think about looking into the `+` menu. Thanks a lot!